# Regular Expresseion in Express routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, wildcard

I have a file which name is like workbox-someHash.js and that hash will be generated every time I deploy my app. I need to serve it on a route with the same name and what I tried so far is

```
  "(workbox-([a-z0-9]{8})[.]js)",
  express.static(__dirname + "/../build/(workbox-([a-z0-9]{8})[.]js)", {})
);
```

But I'm not winning here. Is there anything I forgot to add or should I do it some other way. Would appreciate any help

Comment: You cannot add a regular expression to the path that you pass `express.static()`.  That path must be an actual path.

Comment: @jfriend00 so there is no way to serve a file with dynamic naming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you have a bunch of static files with names that match your regex

```
workbox-([a-z0-9]{8})[.]js
```

And, they are located in the folder:

```
__dirname + "/../build"
```

And, you want to serve those static files automatically, then you can do this:

```
app.use("/workbox-([a-z0-9]{8})[.]js", express.static(__dirname + "/../build"));
```

This will match any path request that starts with a `/` and then matches your workbox regex.  It will then look in the `__dirname + "/../build"` folder for a file with that same name.

---

A solution may actually not be this difficult.  If the `build` folder this references contains only files that can be served publicly, then you could also just do this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../build"));
```

This will take any incoming request and see if the matching path exists in `__dirname + "/../build"`.  If it does, it will serve it.  This will be true whether it's one of your workbox filenames or any other matching filename that is also in that folder.